# How to upload large archives to Amazon Glacier using PHP and aws-sdk v3?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, cpanel, aws-sdk, amazon-glacier

This is my first time working with anything from Amazon. I am trying to upload multiple files into Amazon Glacier using the PHP SDK V3. The files will then need to be merged by Amazon into one.

The files are stored in the home directory of cPanel and will have to be uploaded via a cron job to Amazon Glacier.

I know I have to use the upload multi part method but I am not really sure which other functions it requires to make it work. I am also not sure if the way I calculated and passed the variables is correct.

This is the code I got so far:

```
<?php
require 'aws-autoloader.php';

use Aws\Glacier\GlacierClient;
use Aws\Glacier\TreeHash;

//############################################
//DEFAULT VARIABLES
//############################################
$key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$secret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';   
$accountId = '123456789123';
$vaultName = 'VaultName';
$partSize = '4194304';
$fileLocation = 'path/to/files/';

//############################################
//DECLARE THE AMAZON CLIENT
//############################################
$client = new GlacierClient([
    'region' => 'us-west-2',
    'version' => '2012-06-01',
    'credentials' => array(
        'key'    => $key,
        'secret' => $secret,
  )
]);

//############################################
//GET THE UPLOAD ID
//############################################
$result = $client->initiateMultipartUpload([
    'partSize' => $partSize,
    'vaultName' => $vaultName
]);
$uploadId = $result['uploadId'];

//############################################
//GET ALL FILES INTO AN ARRAY
//############################################
$files = scandir($fileLocation);
unset($files[0]);
unset($files[1]);
sort($files);

//############################################
//GET SHA256 TREE HASH (CHECKSUM)
//############################################
$th = new TreeHash();
//GET TOTAL FILE SIZE
foreach($files as $part){
    $filesize = filesize($fileLocation.$part);
    $total = $filesize;
    $th = $th->update(file_get_contents($fileLocation.$part));
}
$totalchecksum = $th->complete();

//############################################
//UPLOAD FILES
//############################################
foreach ($files as $key => $part) {
    //HASH CONTENT
    $filesize = filesize($fileLocation.$part);
    $rangeSize = $filesize-1;
    $range = 'bytes 0-'.$rangeSize.'/*';
    $sourcefile = $fileLocation.$part;

    $result = $client->uploadMultipartPart([
        'accountId' => $accountId,
        'checksum' => '',
        'range' => $range,
        'sourceFile' => $sourcefile,
        'uploadId' => $uploadId,
        'vaultName' => $vaultName
    ]);
}

//############################################
//COMPLETE MULTIPART UPLOAD
//############################################
$result = $client->completeMultipartUpload([
    'accountId' => $accountId,
    'archiveSize' => $total,
    'checksum' => $totalchecksum,
    'uploadId' => $uploadId,
    'vaultName' => $vaultName,
]);
?>
```

It seems that the declaring of a new Glacier client is working and I do receive an UploadID, but with the rest I am not 100% if I am doing it right. The Amazon Glacier Vault where the files need to upload to and then get merged, remains empty and I am not sure if the files will only show ones the completeMultipartUpload has successfully been executed.

I also receive the following error when running the code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'Aws\Glacier\Exception\GlacierException' with message 'Error executing
>   "CompleteMultipartUpload" on
>   "https://glacier.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXXXXXX/vaults/XXXXXXXXXX/multipart-uploads/cTI0Yfk6xBYIQ0V-rhq6AcdHqd3iivRJfyYzK6-NV1yn9GQvJyYCoSrXrrrx4kfyGm6m9PUEAq4M0x6duXm5MD8abn-M";
>   AWS HTTP error: Client error: 403 InvalidSignatureException (client):
>   The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you
>   provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult
>   the service documentation for details. The Canonical String for this
>   request should have been 'POST
>   /XXXXXXXXXXX/vaults/XXXXXXXXX/multipart-uploads/cTI0Yfk6xBYIQ0V-rhq6AcdHqd3iivRJfyYzK6-NV1yn9GQvJyYCoSrXrrrx4kfyGm6m9PUEAq4M0x6duXm5MD8abn-M
>   host:glacier.us-west-2.amazonaws.com x-amz-archive-size:1501297
>   x-amz-date:20151016T081455Z x-amz-glacier-version:2012-06-01
>   x-amz-sha256-tree-hash:?[ qiuã°²åÁ¹ý+¤Üª¤ [;K×T
>   host;x-amz-archive-size;x-amz-date;x-amz-glacier-version;x-am in
>   /home/XXXXXXXXXXXX/public_html/XXXXXXXXXXX/Aws/WrappedHttpHandler.php
>   on line 152

Is there maybe a simpler way to do this? I do have full SSH access as well if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood uploadMultipartPart.
uploadMultipartPart means, you upload 1 big file, in multiple parts.
and then do a completeMultipartUpload to mark that you have completed uploading one file.

from your code it looks like you are uploading multiple files.

it is possible that you do not actually need to use uploadMultipartPart

Maybe a you could use a regular "uploadArchive"?

ref:

https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/php/post/Tx7PFHT4OJRJ42/Uploading-Archives-to-Amazon-Glacier-from-PHP

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I now realized what my mistake was. There seems to be a few bugs with the PHP SDK v3 and I had to switch back to v2. https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/releases

Answer (score 3):

I have managed this in PHP SDK V3 (Version 3) and I kept finding this question in my research, so I thought I'd post my solution too. Use at your own risk and there is very little error checking or handling.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\Glacier\GlacierClient;
use Aws\Glacier\TreeHash;


// Create the glacier client to connect with
$glacier = new GlacierClient(array(
      'profile' => 'default',
      'region' => 'us-east-1',
      'version' => '2012-06-01'
      ));

$fileName = '17mb_test_file';         // this is the file to upload
$chunkSize = 1024 * 1024 * pow(2,2);  // 1 MB times a power of 2
$fileSize = filesize($fileName);      // we will need the file size (in bytes)

// initiate the multipart upload
// it is dangerous to send the filename without escaping it first
$result = $glacier->initiateMultipartUpload(array(
      'archiveDescription' => 'A multipart-upload for file: '.$fileName,
      'partSize' => $chunkSize,
      'vaultName' => 'MyVault'
      ));

// we need the upload ID when uploading the parts
$uploadId = $result['uploadId'];

// we need to generate the SHA256 tree hash
// open the file so we can get a hash from its contents
$fp = fopen($fileName, 'r');
// This class can generate the hash
$th = new TreeHash();
// feed in all of the data
$th->update(fread($fp, $fileSize));
// generate the hash (this comes out as binary data)...
$hash = $th->complete();
// but the API needs hex (thanks). PHP to the rescue!
$hash = bin2hex($hash);

// reset the file position indicator
fseek($fp, 0);

// the part counter
$partNumber = 0;

print("Uploading: '".$fileName
    ."' (".$fileSize." bytes) in "
    .(ceil($fileSize/$chunkSize))." parts...\n");
while ($partNumber * $chunkSize < ($fileSize + 1))
{
  // while we haven't written everything out yet
  // figure out the offset for the first and last byte of this chunk
  $firstByte = $partNumber * $chunkSize;
  // the last byte for this piece is either the last byte in this chunk, or
  // the end of the file, whichever is less
  // (watch for those Obi-Wan errors)
  $lastByte = min((($partNumber + 1) * $chunkSize) - 1, $fileSize - 1);

  // upload the next piece
  $result = $glacier->uploadMultipartPart(array(
        'body' => fread($fp, $chunkSize),  // read the next chunk
        'uploadId' => $uploadId,          // the multipart upload this is for
        'vaultName' => 'MyVault',
        'range' => 'bytes '.$firstByte.'-'.$lastByte.'/*' // weird string
        ));

  // this is where one would check the results for error.
  // This is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

  // onto the next piece
  $partNumber++;
  print("\tpart ".$partNumber." uploaded...\n");
}
print("...done\n");

// and now we can close off this upload
$result = $glacier->completeMultipartUpload(array(
  'archiveSize' => $fileSize,         // the total file size
  'uploadId' => $uploadId,            // the upload id
  'vaultName' => 'MyVault',
  'checksum' => $hash                 // here is where we need the tree hash
));

// this is where one would check the results for error.
// This is left as an exercise for the reader ;)


// get the archive id.
// You will need this to refer to this upload in the future.
$archiveId = $result->get('archiveId');

print("The archive Id is: ".$archiveId."\n");


?>
```

Comment: This one worked for me except the TreeHash part. Since we're uploading large files, "freading" the file as a whole defeats the purpose of MultiPart uploads. What I did was to call the addChecksum method passing in the returned checksum of the MultiUploadPart method. This way, memory usage is kept to a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

***Note: Solution for uploading multiparts using aws-sdk-php v2. I think it could work on v3 with few changes on the use of class***
`TreeHash`.

Thanks to the [snippet of Neil Vandermeiden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33165845/how-to-upload-large-archives-to-amazon-glacier-using-php-and-aws-sdk-v3/33657915#33657915), I've accomplished the same task but adding a little improvement.

Neil only does a checksum validation for the whole file. It has two possible problems:

- **It could be memory consuming**: remember we're uploading a large file; hashing it to get the checksum, requires to open it and read all of its contents.
- **We're uploading multiple file parts**: we can have problems uploading some parts, ending with corrupted file parts on aws. If we compute and validate every checksum of every part, we can prevent problems.

In the following code we compute the checksum of every file part sent to aws, and we send each of them with the associated file part to the aws api.

Once aws finishes receiving the uploaded part, it performs a checksum of it. If the checksum doesn't match ours, it throws an exception. If it successes, we're sure the part has uploaded successfully.

```
<?php
use Aws\Common\Hash\TreeHash;
use Aws\Glacier\GlacierClient;

/**
 * upload a file and store it into aws glacier
 */
class UploadMultipartFileToGlacier
{
    // aws glacier
    private $description;
    private $glacierClient;
    private $glacierConfig;
    /*
     * it's a requirement the part size beingto be (1024 KB * 1024 KB) multiplied by any power of 2 (1MB, 2MB, 4MB, 8MB, and so on)
     * reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.Glacier.GlacierClient.html#_initiateMultipartUpload
     **/
    private $partSize;

    // file location
    private $filePath;

    private $errorMessage;
    private $executionDate;

    public function __construct($filePath)
    {
        $this->executionDate = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $this->filePath = $filePath;
    
        // AWS Glacier
        $this->glacierConfig = (object) [
            'vaultId' => 'VAULT_NAME',
            'region' => 'REGION',
            'accessKeyId' => 'ACCESS_KEY',
            'secretAccessKey' => 'SECRET_KEY',
        ];

        $this->glacierClient = GlacierClient::factory(array(
            'credentials' => array(
                'key'    => $this->glacierConfig->accessKeyId,
                'secret' => $this->glacierConfig->secretAccessKey,
            ),
            'region' => $this->glacierConfig->region
        ));

        $this->description = sprintf('Upload file %s at %s', $this->filePath, $this->executionDate);

        $this->partSize = 1024 * 1024 * pow(2, 2); // 4 MB
    }

    public function upload()
    {
        list($success, $data) = $this->uploadFileToGlacier();

        if ($success) {
            // todo: tasks to do when file has upload successfuly to aws glacier
        } else {
            // todo: handle error
            // $this->errorMessage contains the exception message
        }
    }

    private function completeMultipartUpload($uploadId, $fileSize, $checksumParts)
    {
        // with all the chechsums of the processed file parts, we can compute the file checksum. It's important to send it as a parameter to the
        // aws api's GlacierClient::completeMultipartUpload. Aws compute on their side the checksum of the uploaded part. If
        // their checksum doesn't match ours, the api throws an exception.
        $checksum = $this->getChecksumFile($checksumParts);

        return $this->glacierClient->completeMultipartUpload([
            'archiveSize' => $fileSize,
            'uploadId' => $uploadId,
            'vaultName' => $this->glacierConfig->vaultId,
            'checksum' => $checksum
        ]);
    }

    private function getChecksumPart($content)
    {
        $treeHash = new TreeHash();
        $mb = 1024 * 1024 * pow(2, 0); // 1 MB (the class TreeHash only allows to process chunks <= 1 MB)
        $buffer = $content;

        while (strlen($buffer) >= $mb) {
            $data = substr($buffer, 0, $mb);
            $buffer = substr($buffer, $mb) ?: '';
            $treeHash->addData($data);
        }
        
        if (strlen($buffer)) {
            $treeHash->addData($buffer);
        }

        return $treeHash->getHash();
    }

    private function getChecksumFile($checksumParts)
    {
        $treeHash = TreeHash::fromChecksums($checksumParts);

        return $treeHash->getHash();
    }

    private function initiateMultipartUpload()
    {
        $result = $this->glacierClient->initiateMultipartUpload([
            'accountId' => '-',
            'vaultName' => $this->glacierConfig->vaultId,
            'archiveDescription' => $this->description,
            'partSize' => $this->partSize,
        ]);

        return $result->get('uploadId');
    }

    private function uploadFileToGlacier()
    {
        $success = true;
        $data = false;

        try {
            $fileSize = filesize($this->filePath);

            $uploadId = $this->initiateMultipartUpload();
            $checksums = $this->uploadMultipartFile($uploadId, $fileSize);
            $model = $this->completeMultipartUpload($uploadId, $fileSize, $checksums);

            $data = (object) [
                'archiveId' => $model->get('archiveId'),
                'executionDate' => $this->executionDate,
                'location' => $model->get('location'),
            ];
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
            $success = false;
        }

        return [$success, $data];
    }
    
    private function uploadMultipartFile($uploadId, $fileSize)
    {
        $numParts = ceil($fileSize / $this->partSize);
        $fp = fopen($this->filePath, 'r');
        $partIdx = 0;
        $checksumParts = [];

        error_log("Uploading: {$this->filePath} ({$fileSize} bytes) in {$numParts} parts...");

        while ($partIdx * $this->partSize < ($fileSize + 1)) {
            $firstByte = $partIdx * $this->partSize;
            $lastByte = min((($partIdx + 1) * $this->partSize) - 1, $fileSize - 1);
            $content = fread($fp, $this->partSize);
            
            // we compute the checksum of the part we're processing. It's important to send it as a parameter to the
            // aws api's GlacierClient::uploadMultipartPart. Aws compute on their side the checksum of the uploaded part. If
            // their checksum doesn't match ours, the api throws an exception.
            $checksumPart = $this->getChecksumPart($content);

            $result = $this->glacierClient->uploadMultipartPart([
                'body' => $content,
                'uploadId' => $uploadId,
                'vaultName' => $this->glacierConfig->vaultId,
                'checksum' => $checksumPart,
                'range' => "bytes {$firstByte}-{$lastByte}/*"
            ]);

            $checksumParts[] = $result->get('checksum'); // same result as $checksumPart. It throws an exception if doesn't
            
            $partIdx++;
            error_log("Part {$partIdx} uploaded...");
        }

        return $checksumParts;
    }
}

$uploadMultipartFileToGlacier = new UploadMultipartFileToGlacier('<FILE_PATH>');

$uploadMultipartFileToGlacier->upload();
```